# Finding file path with os.walk

Tags: python, filepath, os.walk

I have a set of files saved in my laptop. The folder structure is like:

```
Part1(folder)
 Part1(subfolder)
  awards_1990 (subfolder)
     awards_1990_00 (subfolder)
        (files)
     awards_1990_01
        (files)
        ...
        ...
        ...
  awards_1991
    awards_1991_01
      (files)
    awards_1991_01
    awards_1991_01
     ...
     ...
     ...
  awards_1992
     ...
     ...
     ...
  awards_1993
     ...
     ...
     ...
  awards_1994
     ...
     ...
     ...
```

So I am trying to extract the list of file path with os.walk. The code I have is like this:

```
import os
matches=[]
for root, dirnames, dirname in os.walk('E:\\Grad\\LIS\\LIS590 Text mining\\Part1\\Part1'):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        for filename in dirname:
                if filename.endswith(('.txt','.html','.pdf')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root,filename))
```

When I call matches, it returns [].

I tried another code:

```
import os
dirnames=os.listdir('E:\\Grad\\LIS\\LIS590 Text mining\\Part1\\Part1')
for filenames in dirnames:
    for filename in filenames:
        path=os.path.join(filename)
        print (os.path.abspath(path))
```

This one gives me me this result:

```
C:\Python32\a
C:\Python32\w
C:\Python32\a
C:\Python32\r
C:\Python32\d
C:\Python32\s
C:\Python32\_
C:\Python32\1
...
```

Researching on this error. Any idea what to do with this?

Comment: endswith only accepts one item...

Comment: I used it before with multiple items, it worked well.

Comment: ..., but it would accept a tuple of items to look for.

Comment: @Q-ximi But not like you wrote it here.

Comment: @Q-ximi: the names are misleading, rename `dirname` to `filenames` in the `os.walk` for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for filename in dirname:` enumerates individual *characters* in `dirname` *string*. Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

topdir = r'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1'
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(topdir):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.txt','.html','.pdf')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
print("\n".join(matches))
```

You don't need the `for`-loop with `dirnames` here.

Comment: Thank you. When I tried to run this code Python keeps dying on me. Is it a code problem or python compatibility with Windows? I am still running Windows Vista (32bit) OS. The installation path is c:/Python32. It did work before though...

Comment: @Q-ximi: have you tried to define `topdir` variable? "keeps dying on me" is not very informative. Run it from the command line and post the full traceback.

Comment: Ok, I just tried to define the topdir, now it is giving me the ERROR13, permission denied. The code is as below: `import os

matches = []
root=open(r'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1','r')
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.txt','.html','.pdf')):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

print (matches)`

Comment: @Q-ximi: `topdir` must be a *directory path* (a string, not a file object).

Comment: Sorry I just started to learn programming a week. Could you please give me an example of a directory path which is a string. Sorry about the question.

Comment: @Q-ximi: I've updated the answer. btw, *don't use the same name for different purposes* e.g., `dirname` in the code in your question or `root` in the comment above. It leads to errors.

Comment: Oh,no. It worked!!! Thank you sooooo much!!! So can you tell me what was the problem?

Comment: @Q-ximi:  *"crashed again"* is not very informative. [What have you tried to fix the error?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). Copy-paste the code from my question, and run it from the command-line, post the output. If the output is multiline, either [put in in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22132663/edit) or use a [pastebin](https://gist.github.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Function *endswith* takes: *suffix[, start[, end]]*, so if you have more than one suffix, then you need parentheses around them:

```
if filename.endswith(('.txt','.html','.pdf')):
```

Comment: Still not working. Just updated my code in the post.

Comment: To walk over files in a directory tree you can use something like:

`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdirectory):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))`

Comment: I tried    `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdirectory): for file in files: filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))`. It only gave me the last file.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? For the path of all files I found, how do I loop open all of them to read instead of opening them one by one? The path list is like                                     'E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1\awards_1994\awd_1994_96\a9496348.txt
E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1\awards_1994\awd_1994_96\a9496349.txt
E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1\awards_1994\awd_1994_96\a9496350.txt
E:\Grad\LIS\LIS590 Text mining\Part1\Part1\awards_1994\awd_1994_96\a9496351.txt
' ...